# Como remover caracter que não seja uma letra em uma string?

Tags: php

Tenho um *array* de *strings* que me retorna da seguinte forma:

```
Array
(
    [0] => motivação,
    [1] => sentimento33
    [2] => que..
    [3] => 56nos
    [4] => impulsiona\\
    [5] => proporciona
    [6] => investir^^
    [7] => determinado
    [8] => grau?
    [9] => esforço!
)
```

Quero que o retorno seja assim:

```
Array
(
    [0] => motivação
    [1] => sentimento
    [2] => que
    [3] => nos
    [4] => impulsiona
    [5] => proporciona
    [6] => investir
    [7] => determinado
    [8] => grau
    [9] => esforço
)
```

Talvez regex resolveria esse problema, mas não ainda não encontrei uma soluação. Como posso remover caracter que não seja uma letra em uma determinada *string*?

Comment: Acho que bastaria usar algo como o [^A-zÀ-ú].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar `preg_replace` para remover os caracteres que não são letras de uma `string`. Em seguida, você poderá combinar com `array_map`.

```
$callback = function ($value) {
    return preg_replace('/\W+/u', '', $value);
};

array_map($callback, $array);
```

Usei o modificador `u` para reconhecer caracteres acentuados.

A expressão `\W+` significa *qualquer caractere que não seja palavras*.

Comment: não entendi bem o `/W+`, não seria melhor apenas usar o "marcador" de negação e subtituir o que não for `a-zA-Z` por uma string vazia?

Comment: `\W+` significa *any "non-word" character*.Veja na [Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php).

Answer (score 1):

Em Unicode, A primeira letra latina acentuada tem o código `\u00c0` (["À"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00c0/index.htm)) e o último é o `\u024F` (["<strike>y</strike>"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/024f/index.htm)). Você pode selecionar todas as letras utilizando o básico (`a-zA-Z`) e a faixa compreendida entre esses dois caracteres especiais. Assim:

```
[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u024F]
```

E como são faixas entre colchetes, a negação é fácil:

```
[^a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u024F]
```

Agora é só aplicar. Pode experimentar no console do navegador:

```
"Açaí, lingüiça, outras comidas acentuadas etc.".replace(/[^a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u024F]/g, "");
```

Note que assim você remove também os espaços e pontuação. Adicione um espaço nos colchetes se quiser preservar espaços entre palavras, vírgulas e pontos se quiser manter pontuação etc.

Comment: Isso funciona com caracteres compostos?

Comment: Deve funcionar.

Comment: Não é necessário o modificador `u`?