# quais caracteres não podem ser usados em nomes de arquivos?

Tags: php, arquivo

Sabemos que é comum utilizarmos sistemas que salvem arquivos, gostaria de saber quais caracteres são inválidos para serem usados como nomes de arquivos? existe uma função que remove todos caracteres que não sejam letras ?

Comment: Relacionada ou Duplicata de: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184020/57801

Comment: Em que sistema operacional?

Comment: windowns mesmo @Maniero

Answer (score 2):

Ao criar um arquivo ou pasta em seu computador, existem alguns caracteres que não são permitidos utilizar em seus nomes.

Confira quais são eles:

```
\
/
|
?
<
>
*
:
“
```

Os caracteres válidos para nomear arquivos ou pastas incluem todas as letras do alfabeto (de A a Z) e números (de 0 a 9), além dos caracteres especiais:

```
^ 
& 
‘ 
@ 
{ 
} 
[ 
] 
, 
$ 
= 
! 
– 
# 
( 
) 
% 
. 
+ 
~ 
_
```

Fonte: http://www.cursosdeinformaticabasica.com.br/quais-sao-os-caracteres-invalidos-para-a-criacao-de-arquivos-e-pastas/

Sobre a função, veja esta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198378/como-remover-caracter-que-n%C3%A3o-seja-uma-letra-em-uma-string) de outro usuário.

```
$callback = function ($value) {
    return preg_replace('/\W+/u', '', $value);
};

array_map($callback, $array);
```

Comment: Falta adicionar o ponto de interrogação "?" .